# Group by month in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to group by month in oracle, but I'm getting an invalid identifier on the "YEAR" function, not sure why.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT CAST(MONTH(day_date) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(day_date) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS MY_DATE,
sum(cash_sales) as cash_sales, sum(unit_sales) as unit_sales
FROM NC_SALES_CAT_TL
GROUP BY CAST(MONTH(day_date) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(day_date) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

How can I accomplish the desired grouping by month?

Answer (score 3):

Concatenation operator in Oracle is `||`. Not `+`:

```
SQL> select 'a' +' b' from dual;
select 'a' +' b' from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

```
SQL> select 'a' || 'b' from dual;

'A
--
ab
```

---

In addition, [`YEAR`](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.4.2.1/ref/rrefyearfunc.html) is a MySQL function. In Oracle, you will use [`EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ....)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm)

---

Finally, are you aware of the [`TO_CHAR`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm)  function?

So you should rewrite your whole query as:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(day_date, 'MM-YYYY') AS MY_DATE,
       sum(cash_sales) as cash_sales, sum(unit_sales) as unit_sales
FROM NC_SALES_CAT_TL
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(day_date, 'MM-YYYY')
```

Comment: Thanks I've now changed to concatentation operator. Still getting the error on the Year Function though.

Comment: @branches I've edited in a hurry to provide the correct query. Beware of typos though!