# Oracle: group by month

Tags: oracle, date-format

I have such problem, I am working with Oracle database.  in one of my tables there is a column in timestamp format like `06.01.14 08:54:35`
I must select some data by grouping this column only by month.
the result of query for the column if `06.01.14` then must be `Jan.2014` in `MM.YYYY` format, I tried such query

`SELECT to_char(ctime,'mm.yyyy') from table_name`

but the result is not in date format, it is a string format. I could not do it with `to_date` function

Can you help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863875/group-by-month-in-oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course any variation on to_char will result in a string format. That's what it does. You are, I think, confusing how a value is displayed and the data type behind it.

Now if you have a DATE field then you can use

TRUNC(cTime,'MON')

which will truncate to the first of the month and leave it in date format. How you display it is then up to you. But if you are expecting a DATE value to not have a day/hour/minute/second component - then I'm afraid that you don't understand the data type.

Comment: thanks Michael, This is what I wanted. i displayed it on my own taste :))

Comment: in addition, column of table is a timestamp type as you said day/hour/minute/second don't worry

Answer (score 2):

If `ctime` is of type `TIMESTAMP`:

<s>`SELECT EXTRACT(month from ctime) "month" from table_name`</s>

**edit:** if you want month and year like "Jan - 2014", I think all you need is:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(ctime, 'FMMon - YYYY') from table_name
```

(see http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php)

If `ctime` is a string (e.g. type `VARCHAR`) you'll need to convert to timestamp first (so above, instead of `ctime`, replace with `TO_TIMESTAMP(ctime, "MM.DD.YY HH:MM:SS")`

HTH

Comment: Thank you for replying, but this query gives only months, and I need with the years like `Jan - 2015`

Comment: then ask the right question.. The methodology here is sound.  You asked to group by `only month`  to group by year simply add `extract (year from ctime) "year"` and group by both month and year.

Comment: @Faradox is this what you're looking for? (if so, please accept)

Comment: I need that the result must in date format. Your examples give string format.

Comment: @Faradox then you should `SELECT ctime from table_name,... (whatever aggregate function you're trying to do goes here)... GROUP BY TO_CHAR(ctime, 'FMMon - YYYY')` or similar.  On SO, it is always better to be clear up front about what you are looking for (note that your question specifies a string-like result format) and to be willing to generalize the solutions people are trying to give you for your particular use case.